# Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I had created a Storage account which consists Virtual hard disks. (This storage account doesn't belong to any Resource Group as i had created it using the old Azure Portal.)

Then i thought of switching into Azure Resource Manager so,
Now i want to move that Storage account in a resource group in Azure Resource Manager.

I tried running scripts to copy one blob container to another blob container in other storage account within a resource group but it failed.

Is there any possible way?

Comment: Please edit your question to show some of your script code. Otherwise, no real way to help. It's absolutely possible to copy content between storage accounts, regardless if they're created via classic API or ARM API.

Comment: Thanks, i have done. The problem was that i was giving the storage account name in uppercase. But now i changed it to lowercase and all worked well.

Comment: Great - then please post that as your answer (and mark it as such), so that this question may be properly closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, i have done. The problem was that i was giving the storage account name in uppercase. But now i changed it to lowercase and all worked well.